# CSS Button - 100% of parent

Tags: css, xhtml

Can anyone advise on the best cross-browser/device method to style a button with curved edges that will stretch to the width of its parent element?

The button needs to use background images - I was considering the following code - The button needs to stretch to the width of th 90% outer div -  btnContent div will stretch and leftCurve/rightCurve stay the same size width.

```
<div style="width:90%">
 <div class="leftCurve"></div>
 <div class="btnContent">button 1</div>
 <div class="rightCurve"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method

```
<style>
.outerdiv{ width:100%;}
.rightcurve{ background:url(rightcurveimage.png) no-repeat 100% 0; height:20px; padding-right:10px;}
.leftcurve{ background:url(leftcurveimage.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:1%; height:20px; float:left; clear:right;}
.btncenter{ background:url(btncenterimage.png) repeat 0 0; height:20px; float:left; width:99%;}
</style>

<div style="width:100%">
 <div class="rightcurve">
  <div class="leftcurve"></div>
  <div class=btncenter> Button 1</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note: You have to put leftcurve, and btncenter div into rightcurve div

Answer (score 0):

That's not actual code. In any case you will need to put the 90% on the btnContent not on the parent element.

Comment: not actual code? Not sure what you mean here - its Html?  I'm just looking for advice on an approach to apply css to it

Comment: @Paul `style="90%"` is not valid code. And when you said "I was considering the following code" I was sort of expecting an "almost-working" version, not just a placeholder. But looks like someone else helped you out.